# Javascript length of nested lists

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Goal**: given an array of mixed types determine the number of elements at each level. If there are two sub-arrays at the same level, each of their elements count towards to the total number of elements at that level.

**Approach**:

```
Array.prototype.elementsAtLevels = function( level, levelData ) {
  if ( level == undefined ) { level = 0;  } else { level += 1 }
  if ( levelData == undefined ) { levelData = {}; }
  if ( levelData[level] == undefined ) { levelData[level] = this.length} else { levelData[level] += this.length }
  this.map(function(e, i) {if (Array.isArray(e)){ e.elementsAtLevels(level, levelData) }})
  return levelData
}
```

Test case:

```
[
  1,      // 0: 1
  1,      // 0: 2
  1,      // 0: 3
  1,      // 0: 4
  [       // 0: 5
    2,    // 1: 1
    2,    // 1: 2
    2     // 1: 3
  ], 
  [       // 0: 6
    [     // 1: 4
      3,  // 2: 1
      3   // 2: 2
    ],   
    [     // 1: 5
      [   // 2: 3
        4 // 3: 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
].elementsAtLevels()

// Object [ 6, 5, 3, 1 ]
```

**Question**:
Is there a more efficient way to calculate this?

Comment: Don't mutate builtins' prototypes

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou why?

Comment: How should the output look like? Please share exact format.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou nope, because there are two other lists at the first level and these are elements (at least for what I need the function for)

Comment: @SumNeuron You ask for a more **efficient** solution. Where do you see possible improvements in this manner? If you want some general review instead, you might want to ask on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site.

Comment: levelData[level] is once calculated, it is not updated any longer. then how does your problem statement preserves? "each of their elements count towards to the total number of elements at that level."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something very similar to what you have, and in a very rudimentary benchmark, it ran in a little under half the time.

```js
let a = [1,1,1,1,[2,2,2],[[3,3],[[4]]]];

Array.prototype.elementsAtLevels2 = function (level, lData) {
    if (!level || !lData) {
        level = 0;
        lData = {};
    }

    if (!(level in lData)) {
        lData[level] = this.length;
    } else {
        lData[level] += this.length;
    }
    this.forEach(function (v) {
        if (Array.isArray(v))
            v.elementsAtLevels2(level + 1, lData);
    });

    return lData;
}

console.log(a.elementsAtLevels2());
```

I'm guessing the main performance increase might be from the `forEach` vs `map`, `map` creates a new array, where `forEach` does not.

Edit

Here it is in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/matujijebi/edit?html,console)

Comment: if we have multi sub-arrays at the same level, lData[level] is populated with length at the level's last sub-arrays... remaining sub-array lengths is overwritten... are we suppose to add them as per problem statement?

Comment: @ShivajiVarma Excellent point, I've changed to answer to add all sub-array lengths.

Comment: @Joel yeah it seems my copy paste left out the else += part :P (corrected now)

Answer (score 0):

this recursive function should do the work

```js
let arr = [1,1,1,1,[2,2,2],[[3,3],[[4]]]];        

Array.prototype.elementsAtLevels = function(){
   return this.reduce((acc, el, index, currentArray) => {
     if(Array.isArray(el)){
       return acc.concat(el.elementsAtLevels());
     }
     return [currentArray.length];
   }, [])
 }
    
 console.log(arr.elementsAtLevels());
```

Comment: i don't think there's too much you can do on the complexity, you have to loop over each element at each level to check if the current element is an array and then recurse

Comment: Yeah, but you're needlessly recreating arrays with `concat` and `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

This thing performs about the same as yours, but at least it gives correct results:

```js
function elementsAtLevel( array, result = [], level = 0 ){

   result[level] = (result[level] || 0) + array.length
   level++
   for( const el of array ){
      if( Array.isArray(el) )
         elementsAtLevel(el, result, level)
   }
   return result

}

console.log( elementsAtLevel([1,1,1,1,[2,2,2],[[3,3],[[4]]]]) )
```

By correct I mean consistent: you counted subarrays as elements on the first level, but not any other.

---

Here's a prototype version:

```js
Array.prototype.elementsAtLevel = function( result = [], level = 0 ){

   result[level] = (result[level] || 0) + this.length
   level++
   for( const el of this ){
      if( Array.isArray(el) )
         el.elementsAtLevel(result, level)
   }
   return result

}

console.log( [1,1,1,1,[2,2,2],[[3,3],[[4]]]].elementsAtLevel() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it. It resembles yours but it doesn't change the prototype and it uses an array instead of an object for return.

```js
function arrayCounter(arr, level, levelData) {
  if (level === void 0) {
    level = 0;
  }
  if (levelData === void 0) {
    levelData = [];
  }
  //Set default value for level
  if (levelData[level] === void 0) {
    levelData[level] = 0;
  }
  //Count length
  levelData[level] += arr.length;
  //Loop through list items
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var value = arr[i];
    //If array, perform a subcount
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      levelData = arrayCounter(value, level + 1, levelData);
    }
  }
  return levelData;
}
//TEST
var data = [1, 1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2],
  [
    [3, 3],
    [
      [4]
    ]
  ]
];

console.log(arrayCounter(data));
```